# Mounting file in Ubuntu over Samba to home folder

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I am trying to share a folder over samba to a client location `/mnt` in Ubuntu. For mounting to `/mnt` I need to use `sudo`. I read in some articles online that mounting to one's home folder with Samba is a problem since it gives the user the option to save the file locally, as well as in the server share. This can make the data decentralised, if the user does not know about the different physical locations.

My questions are: 1) is this true, and 2) if so, how can this problem be fixed?

I would be glad if anyone answered my questions. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it is not clear what you are trying to achieve from your question.

Here are the questions I think you might be asking:

> This can make the data decentralised, if the user does not know about the different physical locations.

So put something in /etc/motd, or ensure your mounts are created under a subdirectory named "network-shares" or similar. This should be self-evident.

**Can you mount anything in linux without root? Sort-of:**

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96625/allow-non-superusers-to-mount-any-filesystem

**Can you mount samba shared in a homedir?**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/24348/how-do-i-mount-samba-share-as-non-root-user

**2) if so, how can this problem be fixed?**

With confidence in your new found administrator skills. It's not really a problem, it's just your call on how to skin it.

-p